# Change Permissions

Tags: 13.04

I need to change permission for all the files on my hard disk [not system files]. I have retrieved more than 1.2 Lack files and I need permissions to delete or write those files .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BE ROOT!

Enter

`sudo su`

Enter your password

And now you can delete, write or do anything you want!

OR If you want to change the permissions:

`sudo su`

`chmod -R 777 /home/user/`

This will give read,write execute permission to every user for every file.But **this is not recommended**!

Please read

`man chmod`